# Unable to understand this C++ program return value

Tags: c++, ifstream, istream-iterator

I came across the following program in TCPPPL by Stroustrup:

```
int main()
{
    string from, to;
    cin >> from >> to;  // get source and target file names

    ifstream is {from};  // input stream for file "from"
    istream_iterator<string> ii {is};  // input iterator for stream
    istream_iterator<string> eos {};  // input sentinel

    ofstream os{to};    // output stream for file "to"
    ostream_iterator<string> oo {os,"\n"};   // output iterator for stream

    vector<string> b {ii,eos};  // b is a vector initialized from input [ii:eos)
    sort(b.begin(),b.end());   // sor t the buffer

    unique_copy(b.begin(),b.end(),oo);// copy buffer to output, discard //replicated values
    return !is.eof() || !os; // return error state (§2.2.1, §38.3)
}
```

My questions is what is the last line, i.e. `return !is.eof() ||!os;` doing. I know that if main returns non-zero value then it means an error but what is being returned here?

Comment: The title and the question don't really match up?

Comment: @DeiDei Yes, so changed it.

Comment: @AshutoshTiwari Did you try to look at the documentation of [`std::ofstream::eof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof), and [`std::ofstream::operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), to understand what they return?

Comment: this is a legitimate question. Please put down the pitchforks. @AshutoshTiwari to avoid this in the future, please format correctly your questions, and include the reference.

Comment: ...and please dont spam tags. Eg you may have a vector in your code, but the question would be the same if there was no vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
!is.eof()
```

returns whether you **aren't** at the end of the file you are reading (so `true` for not being at the end and `false` for being at the end) and

```
!os
```

returns whether or not your output file is **not** writable. In other words, this program returns:

1. `true` for when you haven't reached the end of your input file (regardless of 2.)
2. `true` for when the output file is not writable (regardless of 1.)
3. `false` for when you are at the end of the file and the output file is writable.

Answer (score 0):

`!is.eof()` tells if reading from the input stream reached the end of the file (hence the expression is true in case of a reading problem).

`!os`, which uses an overload of the `!` operator, is true in case of a writing problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the `main` function completes successfully then it will return `0`, and any other value otherwise. So the line `return !is.eof() || !os;` is doing the following:

`EOF` indicates `end of file`. So,`is.eof()` checks if we reached end of file. If `true` it returns `true or non 0`, and `false or 0` otherwise. The `!` makes the result `inverse` (Reason is `main` exits with `0` on success).

The same thing apply to `os`. If `os` is writable, then it returns `true`,  and `false` otherwise. And `!` makes the result `inverse`.

So that, both of them must exit with `0`.

Comment: how is "is" moving within the file, isn't it pointing to the beginning of the file? Same question with os? –

Answer (score 0):

`is.eof()` returns `true` if end-of-file has occurred for `is`.
This is straightforward.

`os` is an object of `std::ostream` which has [`operator bool()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).
That means `os` is implicitly convertible to `bool`. When done so, it returns `true` if the stream has no errors.

The statement `!is.eof() || !os` is the status of the program.
It can be translated to:

```
either the eof is not occurred for `is` OR `os` has some errors
```

This can be further translated(using De Morgan's laws) to:

```
eof is occured for `is` AND `os` has no errors
```

That means the program is successful if the input stream is read completely and the output was written properly without errors.

Comment: how is "is"moving within the file, isn't it pointing to the beginning of the file? Same question with os? –

Comment: `is` & `os` are not pointers to point to anything. They are objects of `ifstream` & `ofstream`. They internally keep track of the read/write offsets.

Answer (score 0):

#### This program output an ordered list of words found in the input file in a file, return 0 on success or 1 on failure.

The purpose of this program is to show how powerful good iterators can be used to implement concisely a common problem.

- `istream_iterator< std::string >` allow to read the file (aka file input stream) in words, ie using spaces characters as delimiter. `vector< string > b {ii,eos};` initialize the vector by iterating on a file iterator. That is how the content of the files are loaded in memory.
- `ostream_iterator< string> oo {os,"\n"};` allow to write in an output stream (here a file stream) using line return as a separator
- `is.eof()` will be false if the file is not at the end, which means the file has not been read
- !os is the [negative operator of output stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!), which return true if an error has occurred. May errors can occur, but it will mean that the output file will not be created.

Answer (score -1):

it's easy if you break the return lines, you know that it return non-zero for error, so that's a plus.

```
!is.eof() || !os;
```

eof means "end of file", so the first part reads "if it's not in the end of file", the second part means "if there's no file", as you tried to save something into a file, not having a file is an error.

so, the line can be read:

```
return not(are we in the end of the file that we are reading?) 
    or not (the output file exists?)
```

so that will return true of the input file is at end, and the output file exists, false otherwise.

Comment: "so that will return true of the input file is at end, and the output file exists, false otherwise."   You have probably written the opposite of what it will return.